# How to create a java.awt.Image from image data?

Tags: java, image, awt

How to create a java.awt.Image from image data? Image data is not pure RGB pixel data but encoded in jpeg/png format.

JavaME has a simple api Image.createImage(...) for doing this.

```
public static Image createImage(byte[] imageData,
                                int imageOffset,
                                int imageLength)
```

imageData - the array of image data in a supported image format.

Is there anything similar to this available in JavaSE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;

Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

Image image = toolkit.createImage(imageData,imageOffset,imageLength);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use javax.imageio.ImageIO

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(myRawData));
```

**Do not** use the older functions which return an implementation of Image other than BufferedImage. The Image interface is in fact only a handle that might be loaded by a background thread and give you all kinds of headaches.

Comment: Yep, I would trust in ImageIO rather than Toolkit stuff, because of image formats and all that odd things.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource.